# document.querySelector returns null

Tags: javascript

I use the `querySelector` in JS to select html markup that I filled in with a JS script. However, anytime I try to store the divs with a class of `.card` in the `const questionCard`, I get `null`.

Why can't I select the cards?

HTML:

```html
<div class='card-container'></div>
```

JS:

```
const questionBlock = document.querySelector('.card-container');
const questionCard = document.querySelector('.card');

function build() {
    let output = [];

    ...some unimportant code here...

      output.push(
        `
          <div class='card'>
            <div class='question'>${current.question}</div>
            <div class='answers'>${answers.join('')}</div>
          </div>
        `
      );
    })

    questionBlock.innerHTML = output;
}

build();
```

Comment: your html does not have an element with class `card` before you run `build()`

Comment: It is created in the JS.

Comment: see edited comment - `questionCard` is not "dynamic" - the value is set when the code is run

Comment: irrelevant - `questionCard` is null, nothing changes just because you subsequently added an element

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `document.querySelector('.card')` *after* calling `build()`. It cannot find HTML elements that do not exist yet.

```
const questionBlock = document.querySelector('.card-container');

function build() {
    let output = [];

    ...some unimportant code here...

      output.push(
        `
          <div class='card'>
            <div class='question'>${current.question}</div>
            <div class='answers'>${answers.join('')}</div>
          </div>
        `
      );
    })

    questionBlock.innerHTML = output;
}

build();

const questionCard = document.querySelector('.card');
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the more correct answers is:

```
const questionCard = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
```

now: `questionCard` is a live `HTMLCollection`, and `questionCard[0]` will be the first element with class including `card`